# Kuberenetes Internally routing incoming requests to pods which are already processing requests even thought there are idle pods present

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks

I have deployed a compute intensive application in an AKS cluster. Each request takes about 30 seconds to complete. The issue I am facing is a performance related one which affects user experience. When a new request comes into the cluster, sometimes it is routed to a pod which is already serving another request. This result in increased response time for the new request. This happens even when idle pods are available to process new requests. Sometimes this leads to very high CPU utilization and CPU throttling. Is there a way to solve this by making sure that new requests are always mapped to idle pods and not busy ones?

I tried using a readiness probe but still it doesn't work.

Comment: If you arent attaching any loadbalancer to the application service in that case the kube-proxy default mode is 'iptables' so there will be random selection of load distribution will happen.  So you need to attach an loadbalancer to application service where there will option to choose load balancing algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have only heard about the external loadbalancer which routes traffic to various services within the cluster. Can you explain more on this  internal loadbalancer which routes requests from services to pods and how to implement it? Also can we change kube-proxy in AKS to IPVS which allows round robin and least connection routing options?

Comment: For internal LB request you to refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/internal-lb  And for kubeproxy, IPVS request you refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/configure-kube-proxy

Comment: The IPVS configuration seems to be a preview feature in AKS not recommended for production.
Regarding the internal loadbalancer, can we configure it to route incoming requests to pods which are not having loads currently, if not what routing strategies are available with it ?

Comment: Request you to refer following link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/distribution-mode-concepts